# Copied Ubuntu to new laptop. Speed issues

Tags: 14.04

I have a ubuntu 14.04 installed on i3 1.4GHz laptop. To do some real time tasks (software) I bought a new i7 2.9GHz laptop with SSD and have copied the ubuntu partion in the pervious laptop to the new laptop.

My question is that does the previously installed programs and software take the advantage of the speed and high configuration in the newer one or is it better to install a new ubuntu again.

Comment: If hardware configuration is different, I would prefer a fresh install.

Comment: I had a problem with wifi also.. Once I turn ON and turn OFF wifi, I am unable to turn ON again. Needs a reboot again

Comment: You should ask a new  question and provide  your wireless card detail in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Of course will it be faster. Why shouldn't it be able to use a better CPU or disk? The hardware will be used properly, but doing a fresh installation could speed it up a bit more anyway, because of the software (no rests of old packages, fresh settings, ...). But I doubt this would be worth all the time to reinstall it, so just use your copy and be happy ;D.
Greetings!